# Flutter - Showing custom toast from 3rd party library using ios platform method

Tags: swift, flutter

I'm trying to show a custom toast using the "Toast_Swift" library with the iOS method channel. I have set up the method channel in AppDelegate.swift, but I am unsure how to display the toast as described in the library's usage examples.

AppDelegate.swift file -

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Toast_Swift

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
   
      
      
      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
          let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name:"samples.flutte.    .dev/toast",binaryMessenger:controller.binaryMessenger)
      channel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            
          guard call.method == "getToast" else {
              result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
              return
            }
          self.showCustomToast()
          
          })
      
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    
    private func showCustomToast() {
         let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 
          80.0, height: 400.0))

        //something wrong is going on here related to self.view
        self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")
        self.view.showToast(myView)
       
    }
}
```

Here are the example usage of Toast_Swift library
https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

```
// basic usage
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")

// toast with a specific duration and position
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast", duration: 3.0, position: .top)

// toast presented with multiple options and with a completion closure
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast", duration: 2.0, point: CGPoint(x: 110.0, y: 110.0), title: "Toast Title", image: UIImage(named: "toast.png")) { didTap in
    if didTap {
        print("completion from tap")
    } else {
        print("completion without tap")
    }
}

// display toast with an activity spinner
self.view.makeToastActivity(.center)

// display any view as toast
self.view.showToast(myView)

// immediately hides all toast views in self.view
self.view.hideAllToasts()
```

Can anyone help me on how to use the Toast_swift methods to show a toast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you already create one `viewcontroller` instance so please try this because appdelegate does not have any `UIView`.

```
controller.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")
```

instead of this line

```
self.showCustomToast()
```